# Creating threads in Storm Bolt

Tags: apache-storm, distributed-system

I want to fire multiple web requests in parallel and then aggregate the data in a storm topology? which of the following way is preferred

1) create multiple threads within a bolt

2) Create multiple bolts and create a merging bolt to aggregate the data.

I would like to create multiple threads within a bolt because merging data in another bolt is not a simple process. But i see there are some concerns around that I found on internet
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201311.mbox/%3CCAAYLz+pUZ44GNsNNJ9O5hjTr2rZLW=CKM=FGvcfwBnw613r1qQ@mail.gmail.com%3E 
but didn't get clear reason why not to create multiple threads. Any pointers will help.

On a side note does that mean i should not use java8's capabilities of parallel streams as well as mentioned in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html?

Comment: Creating multiple bolts would be the cleaner way to do it. Storm should manage all threads. If you start you own threads, Storm is not aware of them. This might become problematic in case of a failure, ie, no cleanup.

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple threads? Storm works the way it does to allow you to scale by increasing the number of tasks for a bolt. Storm manages all the threading complexity and communication for you so you can focus on the processing. Choice #2 makes a lot more sense to me

Comment: I think it depends on your use case. If you have the choice, then use 2) as it will not "break" storm, it is important to be design-friendly so let storm decide how to distribute the work with a topology. Too much latency in a bolt is a problem, sometimes, you want asynchronous operations in storm (non-blocking tasks), so using threads in a bolt is a way to do so, but there are many others that you should try, if you can do it the storm-friendly way, then go for it.

Answer (score 4):

Increase number of `tasks` for the bolt, its like spawning multiple instances of the same. And also increase the number of `executors (threads)` to handle them evenly.

Make sure `#executors <= #tasks`. Storm will do the rest for you.